# Virtual Memory Statistics per process

Tags: linux, memory, paging, tcmalloc

I am working on a very wierd Memory leak issue and this resulted into the following problem.
I have a process running on my system which increases its Virtual Memory size after a certain  operation is made.Now in order to confirm the issue is not a memory leak issue I want to get statistics for the number of free and used pages held by the process when its currently running.
I am aware of vmstat command which gives the same statistics for the entire system.But for my confirmation I need a **per process vmstat command.**
Does anyone have a idea how this can be done ?

Answer (score 3):

`/proc/PID/smaps` file will give you exhaustive information on all regions of virtual memory held by the given process.

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding in C/C++, dynamic analysis tool like Valgrind could be useful. http://valgrind.org/